# Android resource linking failed, Hardcoded text

Tags: android, android-resources, hardcoded

I don't know the reason why it keep goes on with error. Please help me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXi6n.png)

Answer (score 1):

after viewing your code, I found an error is `app:showAction`.
the correct attribute is `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`, not `app:showAction="ifRoom"`

---

please remove `app:showAction="ifRoom"` & add `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`.